# Graceful shutdown with JmsHealthIndicator in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms

Using Spring 1.5.9.RELEASE on JDK 1.9

Would like to use the `JmsHealthIndicator` to indicate when a connection to a queue manager can't be established after x-number of tries.  Haven't found any good online info om how to configure the `JmsHealthIndicator` other than it should be auto-configured.  Also, not sure how often the indicator is called (i.e. can I control the frequency or not)?  What endpoint it is associated with?